# how to add hebrew to my Samsung s4?

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-s-4, languages, hebrew

I have bought a new samsung s4.

I try to change the OS settings to be in hebrew.

I remembered how to do it from another s4 my sister has.

Went to settings --> Languages and input ---> but there was no "hebrew" to choose.

Then I have tried "more locale 2" but it should solve some other issue, no?

anyhow either i did it wrong or it didn't help as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]